# Cypress- unable to see/capture the popup

Tags: cypress, ui-automation, browser-automation

On the website that i am testing , i have a link -clicking to which brings out a popup.
I am able to locate the link , however clicking on the link results in an "uncaught exception TypeError: Cannot read property popup...". if i suppress the exception the test passes but i still can't see the popup.

I have tried putting waits but it didn't work. So thought of checking here if someone faced a similar issue?

The link element that brings up the popup is below

```html
<a class="locpickerSelect" data-blank="<span>Select Location</span>" data-change="<span>Change Selection</span>" href="#"><span>Select Location</span></a>
```

The popup adds an additional div in the source code , below is what i see in source code when i click on the link

```html
<div class="PopupOverlay" style="inset: 0px; position: fixed;"></div>
<div class="PopupShadow" style="width: 940px; height: 352px; top: 5px; left: 216px;"></div>
<div class="PopupFrame" style="width: 940px; height: 352px; left: 216px; top: 5px;">
<a class="ClosePopup icon cancel-circle"></a>
<iframe seamless="seamless" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" src="https://<myurl>;forFeature=&amp;selectOrgId=" style="display: block; height: 352px;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your cypress code snippet.

Comment: Can't share much but this is what it looks like , i can see in Cypress runner that it is able to locate the element but the click part throw exception
`
describe ('popupTest', function()
{

    it('Launch ID', function(){
    
    cy.visit("https://<corp-website>/")
    cy.get('.locpickerSelect').click({force: true})


   
     } )
}

)
`

Answer (score 0):

The "uncaught exception TypeError: Cannot read property popup..." probably is coming from the application, not the test.

You can put this at the top of the test,

```js
Cypress.on('uncaught:exception', (err, runnable) => {
  return false
})
```

This will suppress any exception from the app, but ideally you want to look at why it occurs.

There does not seem to be anything in the HTML you show that might cause it. Most likely it is in the click handler of `locpickerSelect`.